# Show details onclick on another page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add the functionality to show the details of some elements on click.

```
    <table class = "tabella_spettacolo">
        <thead>
            <tr style = "color:#00a3cc">
                <td>Evento</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <div class = "opacita_spettacolo"> </div>
            <?php

                $queryText2 = ("SELECT NomeEvento FROM eventi WHERE categoria = 'concerto' and DataOra >= current_date ");
                $query2=$dbCon->query($queryText2);
                while($cicle=$query2->fetch_array()){
                    echo " 
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <a class = 'eventi' href = './evento.php'>" . $cicle[0] . "</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>";                                        
                }
                $dbCon->close();
            ?>                       
        </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
```

I need that, for example, when you 'click' on an element of the table, the site redirects to another page with the details of that element.

Comment: So whats not working?

Comment: It sounds like you want your hyperlink to have a URL like `evento.php?id=1` then? I assume there is an `ID` column in the `eventi` table? You need to select that column in your SQL (e.g. `SELECT NomeEvento, ID FROM`...etc and then use it in your code, e.g. `<a class = 'eventi' href = './evento.php?id=$cicle[1]'` . And then of course evento.php must read that ID from the querystring, and fetch the correct event record from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you can handle it in different ways. Depending on your needs and creativity.

**If your row data in your database has an ID**

Render the ID in your element:

Suppose that `$cicle[0]` is your ID now.

```
 <a class = 'eventi' href = './evento.php?ID='+'$cicle[0]'>" . $cicle[0] . "</a>
```

It will render a link liks this so when you click it you will go to the other page and you can require the URL parameters.

```
<a target=_blank href="https://www.w3schools.com?id=12">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

Require your ID `$_GET["ID"]` and `"SELECT NomeEvento FROM eventi WHERE ID = $_GET["ID"]"`

I'm NOT a PHP expert but I think you can get the essence of my suggestion. Anyways, let me know if it's not what you are looking for. Thanks :)

[$_GET and $_POST](https://www.w3schools.in/php/get-post/)

Comment: Why am I seeing mixed concatenation syntax from php and javascript? (`.` and `+`)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var link="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
var arr=[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ];//this array is your php/mysql return array
var x = "";

for (i in arr) {
  $("#tableBody").append("<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td><a href='"+link+arr[i]+"' target='_blank'>"+arr[i] + "</a></td></tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Item No</th>
    <th>Car</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is

`<a class = 'eventi' href = './evento.php'>" . $cicle[0] . "</a>`

you have to do like this

> `$cicle[0]` is may be your eventName OR eventId

```
<a class = 'eventi' href = './evento.php?ID='+'$cicle[0]'>" . $cicle[0] . "</a>
```